# Model is Null outside Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

There are numerous questions like this on stack, but none completely addresses my issue.

I have a model with various properties, one of them is a list:

```
public class MyModel 
{
    ....
    public List<ValuesViewModel>Values { get; set; }
}
```

Where `ValuesViewModel` is:

```
public class ValuesViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StatusOne { get; set; }
    public string StatusTwo { get; set; }
}
```

I've successfuly managed to output them in my View using dropdown lists to modify values like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GenerateReport", "Job", method: FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="container">
        @{
            List<SelectListItem> statuses = new List<SelectListItem>();
            statuses.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Bad",
                Value = "Bad"
            });
            statuses.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Fair",
                Value = "Fair",
                Selected = true
            });
            statuses.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Good",
                Value = "Good"
            });                             
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Values.Count; ++i)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Values[i].Name)                                  
                <p>Status One @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Values[i].StatusOne, Values )</p>
                <p>Status Two @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Values[i].StatusTwo, Values )</p>
            }
        }
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom saveButtons ">Create report</button>
}
```

This way everything works fine, model gets posted to my Controller method `"GenerateReport"` with list data and I'm happy. But!
I have several buttons corresponding to several controller methods, which all use data from `List<ValuesViewModel>Values`. 
And if I put this codeblock:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Values.Count; ++i)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Values[i].Name)                                  
    <p>Status One @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Values[i].StatusOne, Values )</p>
    <p>Status Two @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Values[i].StatusTwo, Values )</p>
}
```

outside of `@HTML.BeginForm`, the model in my controller method will be entirely null i.e.:

```
public ActionResult GenerateReport(MyModel model)
{
    // model is null here!
}
public ActionResult GenerateShortReport(MyModel model)
{
    // model is null here!
}
```

The dumbest solution here is to use `BeginForm` for each button, but I hope and believe that there is another way for that. 
How can I parse my List values to several controller methods without duplicating entire dropdownlist for every button?

Comment: Did you try `[HttpPost]` and `[FromBody]` attributes?

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's what I needed, now it works perfectly! Thank you.
it's so complicated in web..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `formaction` attribute of `<button>` elements inside a single `<form>` to submit to different controller methods (the attribute overrides the form's action attribute.)

```
<button type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("GenerateReport", "Job")">Create report</button>
<button type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("GenerateShortReport", "Job")">Create short report</button>
```

Note the `formaction` attribute is HTML-5 only

Alternatively, you can add `name` and `value` attributes to multiple buttons, and add a parameter in a single method to identify which button activated the submit

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Create report" />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Create short report" />
```

and in the controller

```
public ActionResult GenerateReport(MyModel model, string action)
{
    if (action == "Create report")
    {
        .... // code to generate standard report
    }
    else
    {
        .... // code to generate short version
    }
```

Comment: formaction works fine, however, I've tried to pass another property and It is again a default value...i just added: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.JobId)` before the for loop and it doesn't work, what's wrong? 
JobId is a property inside "MyModel "

Comment: That is not related to this question, so you need to ask a new question. But you need to give more information including your code including showing how/where you setting the value of the property